# No me funciona secuencia FIBONACCI

Tags: c#

estoy aprendiendo C# y desarrollando habilidades como autodidacta, agradezco de antemano.

Por favor pueden decirme que tengo mal en mi código para la secuencia Fibonacci:

---

```
var fibonacciNumbers = new List<int> {1, 1};

foreach(var item1 in fibonacciNumbers)
{
    if(fibonacciNumbers.Count < 20)
    {

        var previous = fibonacciNumbers[fibonacciNumbers.Count - 1];
        var previous2 = fibonacciNumbers[fibonacciNumbers.Count - 2];

        fibonacciNumbers.Add(previous + previous2);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var item in fibonacciNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

El error que muestra es:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare ()
>   <0x2707350 + 0x0001c> in <4c2591e5b92b41cc92fe13502e8be80a>:0    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () <0x2706d00
>   + 0x0006e> in <4c2591e5b92b41cc92fe13502e8be80a>:0    at C.Main () <0x2f48df8 + 0x00118> in <22edcb2fde3742c992b33c05f01a552d>:0    at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) <0x22c19b8 + 0x000e2> in <4c2591e5b92b41cc92fe13502e8be80a>:0
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) <0x22c19b8 + 0x0010e> in <4c2591e5b92b41cc92fe13502e8be80a>:0
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) <0x22bf048 + 0x00022> in
>   <4c2591e5b92b41cc92fe13502e8be80a>:0    at
>   System.CommandLine.Invocation.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync
>   (System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationContext context) <0x2ba70f8 +
>   0x000ca> in <2915f7cee4c54568a16c327bb196b74e>:0    at
>   System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0
>   (System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationContext invocationContext,
>   System.Func`2[T,TResult] next) <0x2ba6600 + 0x0011e> in
>   <2915f7cee4c54568a16c327bb196b74e>:0    at
>   System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.InvokeAsync
>   (System.CommandLine.IConsole console) <0x2b943d8 + 0x001a6> in
>   <2915f7cee4c54568a16c327bb196b74e>:0    at
>   System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationExtensions.InvokeAsync
>   (System.CommandLine.Parser parser, System.CommandLine.ParseResult
>   parseResult, System.CommandLine.IConsole console) <0x2b903b0 +
>   0x000c4> in <2915f7cee4c54568a16c327bb196b74e>:0    at
>   System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationExtensions.InvokeAsync
>   (System.CommandLine.Parser parser, System.String[] args,
>   System.CommandLine.IConsole console) <0x2b2ddc8 + 0x000d6> in
>   <2915f7cee4c54568a16c327bb196b74e>:0    at
>   MLS.WasmCodeRunner.CodeRunner.ExecuteRunRequest
>   (MLS.WasmCodeRunner.WasmCodeRunnerRequest runRequest, System.Int32
>   sequence) <0x2a69198 + 0x00112> in
>   <62ee9ae2d85448949e3cc7803ea8d2c2>:0

Answer (score 4):

El problema que tienes es que estás recorriendo la lista de los números `fibonacciNumbers` a la vez que le vas añadiendo valores a la lista, cosa que no se puede hacer como te indica el error que nos muestras:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified;

Deberías hacer otro tipo de bucle, sin recorrer la lista para ir añadiendole números a esa lista sin que te salte el error al intentar recorrer la misma.

Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
var fibonacciNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 1 };

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    var previous = fibonacciNumbers[i + 1];
    var previous2 = fibonacciNumbers[i];

    fibonacciNumbers.Add(previous + previous2);
}

foreach (var item in fibonacciNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```